# Redirect if URL doesn't contain a string, keep rest of url intact

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

So we're trying to redirect an old subdomain to our new domain, and keep the rest of the URL intact. We're trying to move it all to a subdirectory.

This is easy with the following...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.example\.com/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/test-path/$1 [R=302,L]
```

However, some of the previous sites URLs were actually `test.example.com/test-path/` already, so we'd like to have these ones not double up on the `/test-path/`

That rule is turning URLs like this...

```
test.example.com/test-path/some-page
```

into

```
test.example.com/test-path/test-path/some-page
```

So now we're trying the following...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/test-path/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.example\.com/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/test-path/$1 [R=302,L]
```

And while this will redirect to `example.com/test-path/`, it is now losing whatever came after the normal URL.

```
test.example.com/test-path/other-path
```

is being redirected to

```
example.com/test-path/
```

Hopefully that makes sense on what we're trying to do. Redirect a subdomain to a new domain into a subdirectory, and not double the request-url directory.

**Edit:**

With that most recent attempt, it also doesn't seem to care if the url contains `/test-path/` at all. It still redirects anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.example\.com/$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/test-path/$1 [R=302,L]
> ```

I assume this is just a typo in your question(?), but you have an erroneous slash at the end of your hostname - this will never match.

To avoid duplicating the `/test-path` when it is present on the requested URL, but still redirect to `/test-path`, you can capture this as an *optional* URL-path that is then thrown away if it has matched. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:test-path/)?(.*) https://example.com/test-path/$1 [R=302,L]
```

I've removed the slash and the trailing `$` on the *CondPattern* so that it will match (and consequently canonicalise) FQDN, that end in a dot.

`(?:test-path/)?` is a non-capturing group (so no backreference is created) that captures `test-path/`. This group is then made optional with the trailing `?`.

---

*Aside:*

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/test-path/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.example\.com/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/test-path/$1 [R=302,L]
```

This won't do anything if `/test-path/` is present anywhere in the requested URL. So, if you are seeing a redirect then it would seem "something else" is doing that!

> With that most recent attempt, it also doesn't seem to care if the url contains `/test-path/` at all. It still redirects anyway.

As I say, something else must be doing that. A possible conflict with other directives perhaps? Are you mixing redirects from both mod_alias and mod_rewrite?

Note that these redirects should go at the top of the `.htaccess` file.